# Angular - Cannot get parent component data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm passing a function as parameter from parent to child component. When click event is occurred, function of parent component trigger, but all the property of parent component is undefined. For example,

**Parent Component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor( private notificationService: NotificationService ) {}

    unreadNotification(): Observable<any> {
        // here this.notificationService is undefined
        console.log( this.notificationService );
    }
}
```

**Parent html**

```
<notification-menu [unread]= "unreadNotification"></notification-menu>
```

**child Component**

```
export class NotificationMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() updateUnread: Function;
}
```

**child html**

```
<button type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="updateUnread()">
</button>
```

Now when I click on notification button, `unreadNotification` is triggered, but value of `this.notificationService` in `console.log` is `undefined`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrow` function so that you can use parent component's information. You can try as like as given below.

```
updateUnreadNotification = () => {
   // by using arrow function you can get notificationService information
   console.log( this.notificationService );
}
```

Hope your problem will be solve by this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `@Input()` to pass values from *parent* to *child* and `@Output()` to pass values from *child* to *parent*.

Child HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="update()">
</button>
```

Child Component:

```
export class NotificationMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() updateUnread = new EventEmitter<string>();

    update() {
        this.updateUnread.emit("I am working man!");
    }
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<notification-menu (updateUnread)= "unreadNotification($event)"></notification-menu>
```

Parent Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor( private notificationService: NotificationService ) {}

    unreadNotification(dataFromChild: string) {
        console.log(dataFromChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @nimeresam is good advice - using an `@Output` is an idomatic way to achieve this.

It's worth noting though, that the reason that your original solution doesn't work is due to the way that javascript handles the `this` context.

Writing `(click)="updateUnread()"` is equivalent to saying `this.updateUnread()` with this being `NotificationMenuComponent` - as notificationService does not exist on NotificationMenuComponent you get the undefined error.

To have the context of the parent component used, you would need to bind the context to the `updateUnread` function before passing it into the child component.

This can be achieved either by converting the function to be an arrow functionn, or using `Function.bind`

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

It's normally a good idea to enable the typescript option for `--noImplicitThis` to help catch these errors (though unsure if it will detect it in this case)